# Python Pandas - error: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
set df1["name"] = df2["name] if df1["id"] == df2["id].
```

Both dataframes are of different sizes. I am trying to implement this behavior by writing the code as below:

```
   dtl['name'] = dtlLookUp[["name"]].loc[ dtlLookUp["id"] == (dtl["id"]) ]
```

However, I am getting error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

EDIT :

[image]

Comment: `dtl['name'] = dtlLookUp[["name"]].loc[ dtlLookUp["id"].isin(dtl["id"])) ]` ? Can you come up with a [MCVE] ?

Comment: Could you post the output of **dtl.info()** and **dtlLookup.info()**

Comment: @Vishnudev , done that.

Comment: @harvpan , I want to get the name for that particular id. So, I think I need  comparison:   ==  rather then .isin() .  seems right?

Comment: @frozenshine can you come up with a [MCVE] ?

Comment: The whole point of printing info was to check dtype of id on both dataframe. As I can't see it I guess that you need to use astype(int) on either of the columns.

Comment: the type is non-null object

Comment: @harvpan, I dont see, what else you need to understand this problem. Could you be more specific in what you cant understand from this question ?

Comment: @harvpan, .isin() startegy works. But it's logically incorrect.

Comment: @Vishnudev, I see your ans deleted ( however, I was going to voteup for since, it was in the right direction though not the actual answer). Anywas, Thanks a lot for the help !!

Comment: @frozenshine I saw that the answer wasn't leading to be the correct answer. Happy to see that you solved by your own. It is the best learning you could get.

Comment: @frozenshine, why do you say it is incorrect? :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My problem is solved. Posting it for anyone else who might encounter the same error ( as I search this error but none of the already posted solutions worked for me, So I simply changed the orientation of my problem solving). I treated this problem as a Left Join.

```
    psb = pd.merge(dtl, dtlLookUp, how='left', on=['id'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert id columns on both dataframe to same dtype before condition check. I am assuming the columns named *id* should have **dtype** *int*.

```
df1['id'] = df1.id.astype(int)
df2['id'] = df2.id.astype(int)
```

Put values from the other dataframe based on selection

```
selection = (df1.id == df2.id)
df1.loc[selection, 'name'] = df2.loc[selection, 'name']
```

Comment: If i use astype(int), I get error: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: You need to fill nan before comparing. Use df.id.fillna(0) to fill zeros where the value is empty i.e. np.nan

Comment: ok thanks for that. After filling nan's, `selection = (df1.id == df2.id)` gives the same error as mentioned in the question :(

Comment: @frozenshine How about you use df.reset_index(drop=True) for both dataframe and then select? Pandas uses index for matching